# Adding sitemap in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, sitemap

I want to add a sitemap file in my laravel project. Currently I'm using laravel5.4. I have a sitemap xml file named "sitemap.xml" in the following path

> "resources/views/user/"
>    for site map i have a route as following

```
Route::get('/sitemap',function(){
    return response()->view('user.sitemap')
      ->header('Content-Type', 'xml');
});
```

but when I hit the route it gives the following error

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View
>   [user.sitemap] not found.

the view file is located at user folder correctly then is there any problem in my procedure. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clean the internal cache

```
php artisan route:cache
```

and to update the autoloader (maybe the class hasn't been mapped yet) with composer

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: actually how to do that in shared hosting server

Comment: You can use the Artisan facade inside a controller Artisan::call('cmd'), for composer commands you can use "exec" or "shell-exec" in PHP, but composer file needs to be installed on the system you're working on

Answer (score 1):

Make the get request /sitemap.xml

```
Route::get('/sitemap.xml',function(){
    return response()->view('user.sitemap')
      ->header('Content-Type', 'xml');
});
```